# How to invoke the "Print Pictures" application that comes with Windows 7 from .NET

Tags: c#, .net, windows-7, printing

I'm making a C# application that creates .JPGs. I really like the system where you can right-click on a .JPG in Windows 7 and select `Print`. I would like to invoke that from my C# application in order to replicate the process. How can it be done? I would rather not go through the lengthy process of creating my own dialogs when the functionality is already built into Windows 7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No answer for ages, and I finally found it. So simple. Here it is:

```
   Process p = new Process();
   p.StartInfo.FileName = "file_name.jpg";
   p.StartInfo.Verb = "Print";
   p.Start();
```

Note that the files needs to be a `.jpg` otherwise it might do something completely different or, most likely, nothing at all.

Comment: Does anyone know if there is some way to set the "Fit contents to screen"-checkbox to "unchecked" in that Print Pictures dialog, using .NET?

Comment: For that, you might try looking into [StartInfo.Arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments.aspx), however if I knew so much about that, I wouldn't have had to ask in the first place. A cursory search didn't help for me

Comment: Ok, I will search and hope for the best =)

Comment: I'm getting an error message "Unable to initialize device PRN" on Windows 7.

Comment: @Jeff: Sounds like it means it can't recognise the file (or most likely, the extension). Check your arguments, as I don't have access to the code I wrote for this question anymore.